# which debug validations would you do in order to verify that your std::string is not corrupted

Tags: c++, stdstring

I suspect that a std::string input param is corrupted due to memory corruption (sometimes, not consistently)

again, I do not think there is a bug in std::string, I only suspect that I have a memory corruption somewhere in my code which corrupts my string.

I have added the following validate function:

```
void validate_string(const std::string& inputData)
{
    if (inputData.size() > MAXIMUM_ALLOWED_DATA_SIZE)
        { cout << "data is corrupted. size = " << data.size(); exit(1); }
    const char* cstr = inputData.c_str();
    BOOST_FOREACH(char c, cstr)
        { if (c == 0) {  cout << "data is corrupted. contain NULL"; }}        
}
```

However, I did not succeed to crash the program when in validate_string, nevertheless, I'm still not convinced that my input string is not corrupted

Do you have any suggestion whether how to crash a program when facing a corrupted string?

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, but have you tried valgrind or similar memory checker to see whether you have memory corruption somewhere else that just collides with your `inputData`?

Comment: I am trying to record the input, it's huge and it only happens on customer site. When I'll get that I'll do valgrind, for the meanwhile I can only send them new executable.

Comment: If you are lucky (having some Linux) run it through valgrind otherwise a data breakpoint might help

Comment: @Ezra Do valgrind now with a couple of test inputs to see if there's corruption somewhere else. Your underlying problem need not necessarily have something to do with the specific input.

Answer (score 2):

About the only way to corrupt a `std::string` is to give it invalid data, e.g. initializing with

- a nullpointer, or
- a C string extending into non-adressable region, maybe caused by a dangling pointer.

The first is by far the most common, in my experience with others' reporting of issues.

So, validate the `data()` pointer, which in your function would be `data.data()` (in passing, how about choosing less conflicty names?).

---

If you really want to "crash the program" then there are three means:

- `assert` with assertion that does not hold, and `NDEBUG` not defined,
- `abort`, which terminates without any cleanup, and
- `std::terminate`, which terminates via a user-defined handler, if the program has installed one, and otherwise terminates via `abort`.

In addition there are OS-specific functions such as Windows' `ExitProcess` and `FatalAppExit`, which don't do any C or C++ specific cleanup.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the characters of the string via [isprint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewx8s4kw.aspx):

```
size_t size = s.size();

// check size and internal pointer
if (size > SOME_LARGE_NUMBER || s.c_str() == NULL) {
    // corrupted!
}

// check valid chars
for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
   if(0 == isprint(s[i])) {
       // corrupted!
   }
}
```

To stop the program in the debugger call `DebugBreak()` in windows.
In Linux use `raise(SIGTRAP);`.

Comment: Checking "valid chars" might make sense for a specific instance of `std::string` used for a particular purpuse, but for the general `std::string` **all byte values are valid**. Including that byte value 0 can be present in a valid `std::string`.